# Blazor / Radzen control and html data binding

Tags: data-binding, blazor, webassembly, blazor-webassembly

I was watching a beginner tutorial video on youtube about Blazor with the teacher showing how to create a register and login form.  Please refer to the pic below. The teacher created a bool value name `isBusy` in the code section and, in the html `Disabled` element, he simply assigned it to `isBusy` - so we have `Disabled="isBusy"` The purpose of the `isBusy` var is to disable the reg and login buttons on the form until the api call is completed.

The question that I have is that shouldn't it be `Disabled="@isBusy"` with the `@` sign added?  Please note that he is using a `Radzen` button.  Does that make a difference? If `Disabled="isBusy"` is correct (which appears to be since the demo worked), then what difference between `isBusy` and `@isBusy` in the html?  Thanks in advance.

[image: YouTube Pic]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The use of `@isBusy` is historical ;)

In the beginning you had to use the `@` mark before variable names in order to tell the compiler that you are interested to bind a given variable's value to an Html element's attributes, Blazor component's attributes, etc. Currently, you may use both versions. It took me some time to get rid of the habit of using the `@` mark. Both version are currently legitimate. But it is advisable not to use them interchangeably. Either use one version or another consistently.

Comment: History may be light upon the future, but not in this case. Thank you.